# angular ng module validation issue and Laravel auth password confirmed issue

Tags: php, angular, laravel, typescript

when I create error massage on angular frontend it occurred error like this Property 'name' does not exist on type 'any[]'. even got issue in enter email and password. I created empty array for for display error massage but when I going to compile it. following bellow error will display

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6J6Ro.png)

```
<div class="form-group row">
          <label for="inputName3"  class="col-sm-3 col-form-label" >Name</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="inputName3" [(ngModel)]= "form.name" required>
            <div class="alert alert-danger" [hidden] = "!error.name">
             {{error.name}}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>


  public error = [];

  public form = {
    email: null,
    name: null,
    password: null,
    password_confimation: null

  };

handleError(error) {
  this.error = error.error.errors;
}

  onSubmit()  {
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:8000/api/signup ', this.form).subscribe(
      data => console.log(data),
      error => this.handleError(error)
    );
}
```

Laravel issue Sign UP

if I enter correct password still it shows need to enter match password but when I remove confirmed part  `'password'=> 'required'` it work fine.

```
**User.php**

   public function setPasswordAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($value);
    }


**AuthController.php**


 public function signup(SignUpRequest $request)
    {
        $user = User::create($request->all());
        return $this->login($request);
    }


**SignUpRequest.php** 

  public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name'=> 'required',
            'email'=> 'required|email|unique:users',
            'password'=> 'required|confirmed'

        ];
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular change `public error = [];`to `public error = [] as any;` now it work!!!